# Ubuntu 19.10 doesn't automatically read secondary drive

Tags: mount, ssd, 19.10, drive

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and my secondary SSD isn't read automatically.  It's mounted, and it's detectable by Files, but when I start Clementine, the program can't automatically scan it for the files it contains and I have to go to Files and open the drive before Clementine can detect the files on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Run in terminal:

  ```
  gnome-disks
  ```
- Select your SSD
- Select desired partition on SSD
- Click *Gears* looking button named *Additional partition options*
- Click *Edit Mount Options...* context menu item
- Check the **Mount at system startup** checkbox

[image]

You could also edit your `/etc/fstab` config file adding there UUID of your partition, mountpoint folder, fstype, options, priority as it shown here:

```
UUID=248cea91-2ea8-4065-9039-0c5fcdb3fc98 /home ext4 defaults 0 0
```